# WP page 404 error only on mobile

Tags: redirect, 404-error, mobile

I have a page [here](http://aventric.com/patient-monitors-and-modules-quote-request/) that's redirecting to a 404 only on mobile. I flushed my permalinks, checked all my plugins, etc. and can't figure it out.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: That link does redirect to 404 page on my laptop. Probably you haven't cleared the browser cache, and seeing the old content.

Comment: On desktop it's fine though. Even if I resize my browser it's fine.

Comment: There is no difference between desktop and laptop browsers ( assuming the OS is the same ). Try to access the page in the private mode ( ctrl + shift + p in FireFox, ctrl + shift + n in Chrome ) and check if you see the 404 page.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did try incognito on my android phone and same thing. 404. I'm stumped!

Comment: Hey, I check on my IOS device and it's working fine for me :), maybe you should try to clear all browsing data from your browser, or check with any new device.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this. I had the page in draft mode. Hence, it was only showing when I was logged in.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153058)

Comment: @cjbj Note that the author answered their own question in this case.

Comment: @swissspidy Yes, I saw that. I also voted to close the question.